# LinkedIn cold message got me a connection but no response to message

Tags: linkedin, networking

I recently cold messaged someone on LinkedIn who works at a company I want to interview with. I essentially expressed my interest in his duties at work and wanted to talk about it.  The employee added me as a connection(he initiated the request) but never responded to my message.

How should I respond now? He may be busy or just forgot to respond or perhaps not interested .  I plan to wait a full week before sending another message. What should I say and expect at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely wait a week.  Once that week is up tho you may want to respond with something simple restating why you wanted to connect.

"Thank you for adding me as a contact.  I was hoping that you might have some time to discuss your company and job with me.  I am interested in the Widget Production job and I was interested to hear your opinion as a employee of the company"

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Its extremely unlikely someone will discuss intimate insider details of a company with a cold caller - when someone does that to me (be it "Im interested in working there, please tell me about your duties, processes and technologies" or some sales pitch that is invariably similar), I either hang up (if its a phone call) or bin the message (email, linkedin etc).

Why? Because its called "social engineering" in security circles, and can land employees in trouble if they divulge sensitive information.

If you are interested in a position, contact the HR department or the hiring manager. If they arent advertising, they almost certainly arent looking and wont waste time on you.